# Don't let AdMob ads request focus?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, admob, ads

I have a EditText in a layout, and I also have AdMob ads at the bottom of the layout, when someone enters something in the EditText theres suppose to be a "Done" button in the button right corner of the keyboard, but after I added AdMob it has a "Next" button, and when you press it, it focuses on the Ad! Is there a way to disable this?

My XML:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXX"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="XXXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

My Java:

```
    if (showAds == true) {
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
                         }
```

Note: I dont know if this matters, but I am using a ViewPager so the AdView is on my Main.xml layout file and the EditText is on the Layout that my ViewPager inflates.

Comment: Does your `AdView` XML object have the `android:focusable="false"` attribute?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to retain the "Done" button in your `EditText`, add this attribute to it: [`android:imeOptions="actionDone"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionLabel). This will force the "Done" button to appear on soft keyboards.

If you want to retain the "Next" button instead, and have it skip the `AdView`, you can use [this method](http://androidadvice.blogspot.ca/2010/10/soft-keyboard-next-button-not-working.html) to skip over the `AdView` when hitting "Next".

Comment: Thank you! The `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` works great for me, because I only have one `EditText` in that activity! :)

Comment: If all is working well for you, consider marking this answer as right, so others with this issue can find the solution! :)

Comment: Sorry about that! It wouldn't let me within 10 minutes then it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for me, after editText looses focus ACTION_DONE is triggered, AdMob webView gains focus and stays focused unless user touches the screen. To correct this either remove focus from current focus or close soft keyboard

```
etAddNote.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {           
                activity.getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

or close soft keyboard

```
etAddNote.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this tag in your root layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Ex.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        .
        .
        .
        .
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```